# Retrieve Subnet ids for map variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, subnet

I have created subnet as map variable for availability zone and CIDR block and

```
variable "public_subnets_list" {
  type        = map(any)
  description = "Public Subnets"
  default = {
    "ap-south-1a" = "10.0.1.0/24"
    "ap-south-1b" = "10.0.2.0/24"
  }
}
```

This works fine for creating subnets under my custom VPC with below code

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {

  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc.terraform_vpc
  ]

  for_each          = tomap(var.public_subnets_list)
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = each.value
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.terraform_vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "Public_Subnet_${each.key}"
  }
}
```

How do I retrieve and display the subnet id created for respective AZs from output which i get from `aws_subnet.public_subnet[*]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#splat-expressions-with-maps), splat expressions do not work with resources that use the `for_each` argument.

To retrieve a list of subnet IDs using your Terraform configuration, you can do the following:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = [for subnet in aws_subnet.public_subnet : subnet.id]
}
```